# Populate array of objects in Javascript using two different values as range

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-wrangling

Having a an array of objects with the following structure:

```
[{value: "a", start: 1950, end: 1954, description: "aaa"},
{value: "b", start: 1953, end: 1956, description: "bbb"},
{value: "c", start: 1960, end: 1962, description: "ccc"}]
```

how can I populate the array to get the following result using javascript?
I want to populate the array creating a new object per each `year` contained between `start` and `end`.

```
[{value: "a", year: 1950, start: 1950, end: 1954, description: "aaa"},
{value: "a", year: 1951, start: 1950, end: 1954, description: "aaa"},
{value: "a", year: 1952, start: 1950, end: 1954, description: "aaa"},
{value: "a", year: 1953, start: 1950, end: 1954, description: "aaa"},
{value: "a", year: 1954, start: 1950, end: 1954, description: "aaa"},
{value: "b", year: 1953 ,start: 1953, end: 1956, description: "bbb"},
{value: "b", year: 1954, start: 1953, end: 1956, description: "bbb"},
{value: "b", year: 1955, start: 1953, end: 1956, description: "bbb"},
{value: "b", year: 1956, start: 1953, end: 1956, description: "bbb"},
{value: "c", year: 1960, start: 1960, end: 1962, description: "ccc"},
{value: "c", year: 1961, start: 1960, end: 1962, description: "ccc"},
{value: "c", year: 1962, start: 1960, end: 1962, description: "ccc"}]
```

My understanding is that I should write a for loop to map the results but I am having trouble seeing how I can account for the `start` and `end` variables of each original `value`.

Comment: Please, take a [tour], read [ask], [edit], and create a [mcve]

Comment: `{value: "a", year: 1953, start: 1950, end: 1954, description: "aaa"},` could you explain this line?

Comment: Same as [last time you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682795/populate-array-with-objects-between-two-values), please show what you've tried

Answer (score 3):

Using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) should get you there.

```js
const data = [
  {value: "a", start: 1950, end: 1954, description: "aaa"},
  {value: "b", start: 1953, end: 1956, description: "bbb"},
  {value: "c", start: 1960, end: 1962, description: "ccc"}
];

const result = data.flatMap(({value, start, end, description}) => {
  return Array.from({length: end - start + 1}, (_, i) => start + i)
              .map(year => ({value, year, start, end, description}));
});
  
console.log(result);
```